# How do you properly follow a subjunctive with a related statement?

Tags: meaning, subjunctive-mood

I recently wrote the following:

> …even if the story were originally true, there's no way that Obama was
>   president when it happened.

And then I stared at it, trying to figure out if the second phrase implied that it *had* happened. I thought about other ways to phrase it, *…when it would've happened*, etc, but everything felt more cumbersome than the original. Does the second phrase belie the subjunctive and make it sound as if the story *is* true? If so, how could I phrase it better?

Comment: Seems folks are interested in the context. You'll see why I avoided it at first. There's this [tale of a professor who taught his class about socialism by failing them](http://www.snopes.com/college/exam/socialism.asp) that has been appearing on my Facebook stream. The particular edition that I've gotten twice now has explicitly stated that the socialism in question is "*Obama's socialism*". I looked the story up and found out that it's unlikely this story started the rounds while Obama was PoTUS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't for the life of me understand what the word *"originally"* is doing there, but let that pass...

I see nothing logically or grammatically wrong with *"when it happened"*, because *"even if"* has already invited us (for the sake of argument) to suppose that it *did* happen.

Without more context it's all a bit vague, but I'm inclined to suspect that possibly it might have been better to say *"no way that Obama* **would have been** *president"*.

Comment: I agree. Clauses that are part of a hypothetical situation is normally in the simple past. And the main clause should have *would* or *might*, or another conditional auxiliary.

Comment: Thank you for letting my use of *originally* pass. I think I meant to say *actually*.

Comment: @kojiro: I can't put my finger on it, but *"there's no way"* bothers me a bit too. Perhaps because of your *"originally"*, I assume "the story" goes back long enough that Obama couldn't *feasibly* have been in power (maybe I'm getting old, but it seems to me he's only just taken over). Saying *"there's no way"* seems to imply someone might challenge that, which just feels odd to me. I'd just say *"Even if it were true, Obama wasn't in power then"*.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the other answer.  The problem is actually with the subjunctive itself.  The sentence is saying something like:  Assume there's a story that happened when Bush was president.  Even if the story WAS originally true (during a previous presidency), the story has since morphed, and there's no way that Obama was president when the original event happened.
I.e. it should be:
…even if the story was *originally* true, there's no way that Obama was president when it happened.  (The current version of the story isn't true; the previous version was.)

Comment: +1. I have to like this answer because it solidly defends my originally improper use of "*originally*".

Comment: Hmm. I don't understand this answer at all. If a story *was* true, it *is* true. Only apparently it's no longer the same story, and it [about?] a different president anyway. And we're worrying about the correct grammar for discussing the truth of this story? I'm not sure I live on the same planet as you guys.

Comment: I am assuming the President is a part of the story.  For example, "Can you believe this guy?  Congress wanted to do such-and-such very reasonable thing and the President vetoed it."  Maybe the original story *was* true, in that Bush did veto it, but it's not true the Obama did.

Comment: *that Obama did

Comment: oic. In Britain, I think if we hear some unusual story about what "the Prime Minister" did, we don't usually just seamlessly transfer it to the next person to take office. Unless it's a joke, I suppose, in which case you might amend it to the current person to make it seem more topical. Today it's *"In Soviet Russia, Putin votes for YOU!"*, but when he's eventually replaced, I guess we'll just change the name and keep telling it.

Comment: Any way you slice it, "*originally*" is confusing. If I really meant it in the sense described in this answer, I probably should've written "*…even if the story were true in any form…*" or some such. But that's a different http://english.stackexchange.com/ question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers:  I'm not arguing for that kind of portability the office.  I was speaking from the point of view that in the current highly polarized political environment in the States, it is *very* common for ideas and events and words to be attributed wrongly, intentionally or not.  Fact checking is not exactly the highest priority in certain circles.  I won't say any more lest this be viewed as a politically motivated (which it isn't).  BTW, I say this as an observer (Canadian living the US for over a decade), so I actually do have a point of comparison outside the US.

Comment: @FumbleFingers:  ... Bottom line:  I would not be surprised if someone misremembered/misheard/misreported some event to wrongly port it from one politician onto another.